# Change wordpress snackbar duration

Tags: wordpress

When updating a blogpost using WordPress I am getting a snackbar info that blog post was updated successfully. That snackbar vanishes after couple of seconds. Is there a way to configure how long will that snackbar remain active?

Comment: Did you ask to https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues ? Did you find an answer?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand how is this an issue, and why should I post it on gutenberg repo. I mean I could label it as a question over there, but I believe it would reach more people here...  I am not quite experienced with WP, looks to me that this is a core WP related question... hmh..

Comment: Gutenberg is part of the WordPress Core for quite a few times now and the Snackbar has been implemented in it on june 2019. And in fact there is already an opened issue for accessibility reason of the snackbar, including **too short duration** https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/16549